# What is the difference between absolute and relative SVG path?

Tags: html, svg

I know that capital letter for absolute and lower letter for relative 
but I don't understand the difference between both of them 
and when I can use each kind.

For example :
This example give me different shapes when i use capital letter and lower one.

```
<svg height="210" width="400">
    <path d="M150 0 L75 200 L225 200 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: **MDN:** [An uppercase letter specifies absolute coordinates on the page, and a lowercase letter specifies relative coordinates](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths)

Comment: Absolute: "I have to work till 3 o'clock". Relative: "I have to work 3 more hours". Absolute: "Turn to north." Relative: "Turn to your right". Absolute: "Step to the line." Relative: "Step 2 paces forward." Absolute: "I like the living room to be 20°C (68°F)." Relative: "I would prefer the room ten degrees warmer."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With relative (lower case) commands, the coordinates are calculated relative to the endpoint of the last path segment.

So in the case of your path:

```
M 150 0
L 75 200
L 225 200
Z
```

the path passes through the coordinates as listed.

However with relative commands you would get the following actual coordinates:

```
              Actual         How this was calculated
             --------------- --------------------------------------
m 150 0       (150, 0)       (0 + 150, 0 + 0)
l 75 200      (225, 200)     (150 + 75, 0 + 200)     (ie. lastX + thisX, lastY + thisY)
l 225 200     (450, 400)     (225 + 225, 200 + 200)
z                            (Z and z have identical behaviour)
```